NextJS 15, Auth, Sequelize, Database
I have been struggling with getting the authentication and authorization with credentials using sequelize and a local database up and running. Not using any social providers. Not sure if the sequelize adapter needs to be installed as well. The Auth.js documentation is not clear and complete in this section.
Any help and/or links greatly appreciated. Thanks!
